# Kendo UI and Angular JS - Prevent all characters from typing except for date of format MM/DD/YYYY

Tags: angularjs, datetime, kendo-datepicker, kendo-datetimepicker

I'm using Kendo datepicker to allow the user to enter the date. However I want to allow the user to type only date in particular format, i.e., **MM/DD/YYYY**

```
<input kendo-date-picker placeholder="from" class="form-control" id="fromDate"  ng-keydown="validateDateEntered()" />
```

Now when a user enters something in the input field, I do the validation like:

```
$scope.validateDateEntered= function () {
                   $("#fromDate").kendoDatePicker({
                       format: "MM/dd/yyyy"
                   });
               }
```

Doing this still allows a user to type invalid characters. Just want to understand how can I allow user to only enter date in **MM/DD/YYYY** format and discard everything else.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP).*

After some research, I've found the solution as:

```
<input kendo-date-picker placeholder="from" class="form-control" id="fromDate" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57 || event.charCode == 47' />
```